# Is there any way to disable deep link on Fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-deep-link

I implemented an app using NFC which has URL link. So, When NFC is on, the mobile detects URL and opens my app.

I made it happen like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".view.main.MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->

        <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
</activity>
```

However, the problem is, I have many activities and fragments. It works even while I use my application and It keeps open my application on each and every activities and fragments.

I don't want this behaviour. I want it detects URL just out of my application. How can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: share your `Activity` codes please

Comment: Why do you need it? There is any lines of code for this. I just have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: you want to avoid the activity to start when opening a `url` inside your app?

Comment: Yes. All the acticities while I am using the app. I don't want re-launching my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it single task to avoid multiple opening of the activity

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

also read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode) doc maybe help you

Comment: I think it just uses single process. But It still detects `deeplink`. Is there any better way to avoid Deeplink?

Comment: If explain exactly the case that you want to avoid it , i will help you to figure this out. I think I don’t know exactly what you trying to do and what is the case that make many activities to open.

Comment: What do you need to know to figure it out? I think I explained all above. In my case, I have just one activity and fragments. But I also want to know in other cases.

Comment: Just put your activity codes so i can do a testing and I’ll get back to you with an answer